# How to remove entire row basis of a String in the cell in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a xlsx file which contains two last rows in the end , i have to excluse the rows on the basis of the cell values it contains.i.e My excel contains Total India(10%) and Total(10%) in its last two rows so i have to exclude the  two rows on a basis of Total keyword. I am using the following approach but its not working

```
@Override
public List<String> processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " started");
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            if(currentRow.getRowNum()==0 || currentRow.getRowNum()==1|| currentRow.getRowNum()==2|| currentRow.getRowNum()==3|| currentRow.getRowNum()==4|| currentRow.getRowNum()==5|| currentRow.getRowNum()==6|| currentRow.getRowNum()==7|| currentRow.getRowNum()==9|| currentRow.getRowNum()==10|| currentRow.getRowNum()==11) {
                continue;
            }else {
            Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);
            if (!cellValue.isEmpty()) {
                row.append(cellValue);
            }

            // trying to remove the rows containing total --------------------------------------->
            int rowNums = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            for(int k =0;k<rowNums;k++) {
                currentRow = sheet.getRow(k);
                if(currentRow !=null) {
                    for(int j=0;j<currentRow.getLastCellNum();j++) {
                        currentCell = currentRow.getCell(j);
if(currentCell !=null && currentCell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.STRING) && currentCell.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().contains("total")){

                            sheet.removeRow(currentRow);
                            rowNums++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------->

            //adjusting the cell values with the | or BLANK 
            if(currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                row.append("");
            }else {
            row.append(SEPARATOR);
             }
            }
        }
        if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());
        }
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " completed");
    return rows;
}
            }
```

Can anyone help ??

Comment: Can anyone please help ?? i am not getting any idea

Comment: should the rows be actually removed (shifted up) of just no content?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer just no content

Answer (score 2):

This is my little test program. It removes every row that contains the word `total`. You will have to remove the code that you don't need (first 2 and last line probably)

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsx"));
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int rowNums = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
for (int i = 0; i < rowNums; i++) {
    XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(i);
    if (r != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            XSSFCell c = r.getCell(j);
            if (c != null && c.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.STRING)
                    && c.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().contains("total")) {
                sheet.removeRow(r);
                rowNums++;
            }
        }
    }
}
wb.write(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("test2.xlsx"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW));
```

Updated for your code:

```
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
int rowNums = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
for (int k = 0; k < rowNums; k++) {
    Row currentRow = sheet.getRow(k);
    if (currentRow != null) {
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            if (currentRow.getRowNum() <= 11 && currentRow.getRowNum() != 8) {
                continue;
            } else {
                Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);
                if (!cellValue.isEmpty()) {
                    row.append(cellValue);
                }
                if (currentCell != null && currentCell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.STRING)
                        && currentCell.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().contains("total")) {
                    sheet.removeRow(currentRow);
                    rowNums++;
                }
                if (currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    row.append("");
                } else {
                    row.append(SEPARATOR);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this exception Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1258)
 at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellImpl.getF(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.isFormulaCell(XSSFCell.java:659)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellTypeEnum(XSSFCell.java:690)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellType(XSSFCell.java:678)
 at com.excelmanager.SecondActivity.processSheet

Comment: you have 4 nested loops now. pack everything inside my for-loops

Comment: Sorry i can not change the existing code structure , i have to maintain them